# Error: using abs Complex integers are not supported

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, telecommunication

I get class:int16 type data using "audioread(filename, 'native')", which is a data IQIQIQ... stream. Then, I use complex(I, Q) to form the complex data samples. When I do abs(complex(I, Q)) to get the sample amplitude, I get an error: "Error: using abs Complex integers are not supported". Any advice on how to solve this problem?

Comment: What file type is the audio in? Any change you could post the full code block you are currently using?

Comment: It is a .wav data stream. I think, for any native data of being int16 data stream, you may get the same error if you operate on the data as I described above. The IQ raw data I tried is the "I/Q Raw" on the right download link at the location: https://www.sigidwiki.com/wiki/Terrestrial_Trunked_Radio_(TETRA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting `complex(I,Q)` as double before calling `abs()` may be an option. Then the result can be re-casted as type `int16`. I believe the `abs()` function expects a `double`, `complex double` or `single` as input to compute the magnitude. Since the data is complex the only types allowed are `singles` and `doubles`. Assuming you're looking for the magnitude of the complex data this may suffice. If you're looking to just take the absolute of the components calling `abs()` on channels/vectors `I` and `Q` before calling `complex()` may be an option.

### Casting as Type `single`

```
Audio = audioread("TETRA IQ.wav",'native');
I = Audio(:,1);
Q = Audio(:,2);

Complex_Pair = complex(I,Q);
Complex_Pair_Double = single(Complex_Pair);
Magnitude = uint16(abs(Complex_Pair_Double));
```

### Casting as Type `double`

```
Audio = audioread("TETRA IQ.wav",'native');
I = Audio(:,1);
Q = Audio(:,2);

Complex_Pair = complex(I,Q);
Complex_Pair_Double = double(Complex_Pair);
Magnitude = uint16(abs(Complex_Pair_Double));
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**